# freeswitch esl originate via dynamic gateway

Tags: freeswitch

we need to originate calls in ESL via a gateway defined in the users database profile. it cannot be preset in xml

so how can we send the username/password and proxy etc to freeswitch via ESL when sending the originate command?

we are currently using

```
SwitchApi("originate", "{origination_caller_id_number=12123334444}sofia/gateway/MyFoneComp/17185551212 &park")
```

but of course this requires us having a gateway preset in the xml files named MyFoneComp

a similar question is here: http://lists.freeswitch.org/pipermail/freeswitch-users/2014-January/102452.html but without a practical solution

how can this be accomplished automatically?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

if you don't need to authenticate against the remote server, you just use the bridge destination like `sofia/external/user@domain`.
If you need to authenticate, the only way is to create a gateway in the XML configuration. This XML can also be delivered by mod_xml_curl if you don't want static XML.